# UITextView hangs on very long pastes - how to catch and avoid?

Tags: ios, ios6, uitextview

In the course of developing an app someone submitted a bug report to me - "Cannot paste long text into text field". Sure enough, it hangs with the "Paste" bubble remaining blue from the tap and nothing ever happening. I experimented a little and found that everything works with a roughly 60,000 character file (and it would not take a worryingly long time), but 65537 would kill it every time.

I experimented further and found some third party apps as well as the "Notes" app show the same behaviour.

If this is a real problem in UITextView (in iOS6) I don't expect to be able to fix it so that huge text can be pasted in but I would like to avoid the hang if possible. Can anyone suggest a way of catching the text before it hangs the UITextView?

edit: Thanks to rmaddy, here's what I used to make it work:

```
#import <MobileCoreServices/UTCoreTypes.h>

#define kUITextViewMaximumPaste (65000)
```

...

```
- (void)paste:(id)sender {

  UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
  NSString *type = (NSString *)kUTTypeText;
  if ([pb containsPasteboardTypes:@[type]]) {

    NSString *txt = [pb valueForPasteboardType:type];
    if([txt length] > kUITextViewMaximumPaste) {

      [pb setValue:[txt substringToIndex:kUITextViewMaximumPaste] forPasteboardType:type];
    }
  }

  [super paste:sender];
}
```

Comment: Side note - if you can make a trivial test app that replicates this issue you really should submit a bug report to Apple at bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: You could subclass UITextView and implement `paste:` to try to catch this situation before it can hang. I haven't tried that, but it's the first thing I'd try.

Comment: Yes - bug submitted to Apple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a need to do something similar but for different reasons. What I did is implement the `paste:` method in my custom view that contained the `UITextView`. As matt suggested in the comment, it may be best to create your own custom subclass of `UITextView` and implement the `paste:` method:

```
- (void)paste:(id)sender {
    if ([[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] containsPasteboardTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(NSString *)kUTTypeUTF8PlainText, nil]]) {
        NSString *txt = [[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] valueForPasteboardType:(NSString *)kUTTypeUTF8PlainText];
        if (txt.length > 65535) {
            // oops - too long
            // either truncate or ignore

            return;
        }
    }

    [super paste:sender];
}
```

You may also need to handle other pasteboard types. If a user copies and paste part of a webpage, you may see other types being pasted.